# Laravel 5 email error handeling when username or password is wrong

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, smtp

I'm working first time on sending mail using smtp in Laravel.

I have configured my gmail details and every thing is working fine and I'm getting mail to my inbox.

But I want to know how to handle error/exception when provided gmail information like Username or Password is wrong.

Right now when I provide a wrong password it is taking me to error screen with following message:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 f191sm3044706pfa.26 - gsmtp"
```

I have tried adding some code in app\Exceptions\handler.php as below

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    //This is my code
    if ($e instanceof Swift_RfcComplianceException){
        return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('error',"We have issue sending you an email");
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

My smtp details in .env file are: (Working fine)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ADDRESS=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_NAME=Arun Singh
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Code snippet for sending mail: (Working fine)

```
Mail::queue('/emails/test', array('firstname'=>'arun'), function($message){
    $to_email = 'toemail@gmail.com';
    $to_firstname = 'Sanju';
    $to_lastname = 'Singh';
    $message->to($to_email, $to_firstname.' '.$to_lastname)->subject('Welcome to the XYZ!');
})
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you want to handle the `Swift_TransportException` you should check `if ($e instanceof Swift_TransportException)` in your custom exception renderer

Comment: Thank you it worked. Can you tell me how to read the exception message to display to the end user.

Comment: Yes, you can access the exception message with the getMessage function of the Exception object: `$e->getMessage()`

Comment: Yes I can read the message now, but still it is saying `Call to a member function send() on a non-object`. now to fix this one.
I'm trying to do:  
`$status = Mail::queue('/emails/test', array('firstname'=>'arun'), function($message){  
$to_email = 'arunsingh0430@gmail.com';  
$to_firstname = 'Arun';  
$to_lastname = 'Singh';  
$message->to($to_email, $to_firstname.' '.$to_lastname)->subject('Welcome to the Adelphi!');  
});  
echo $status;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your error handler, the exception that your trying to catch is

```
Swift_RfcComplianceException
```

But the exception that is being thrown is

```
Swift_TransportException
```

To catch the transport exception, just add this to your error handler:

```
if ($e instanceof \Swift_TransportException){
    return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('error',"We have issue sending you an email");
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Can you tell me how to read the exception message to display to the end user.

Comment: Awesome, if you want to use the message the exception is giving you, you could just do something like this:
`return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('error', $e->getMessage());`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  
Can you please tell me how I can access `$to_email`, `$to_firstname` and `$to_lastname` variables in the mail function.
For the following code the variables are not being identified and an error is thrown.

    `$to_email = 'to_email@gmail.com';  
    $to_firstname = 'Arun';  
    $to_lastname = 'Singh';  
  
    Mail::queue('/emails/test', array('firstname'=>'arun'), function($message){  
        $message->to($to_email, $to_firstname.' '.$to_lastname)->subject('Welcome '.$to_firstname.' to XYZ!');
    }); ` 
I'm fetching these variables from db

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how mail variables work, look through https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail and there should probably be some useful hints.

Answer (score 0):

In my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= angambameetei93@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD= xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Same error i got it but after long time i fixed it by

```
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
```

Here, Less secure app access must be ON

```
Allow less secure apps: ON
```

Thanks.